# Comparing the value of a computed variable, defined by target wildcard

Tags: macos, makefile

I'd like to be able validate that required arguments have been passed to my make targets. Rather than defining similar logic for each target, I'd like to be able to reuse the same piece of code.

This is my current idea, which does not work:

e.g.

```
.PHONY: _validate-arg-%
_validate-arg-%:
ifeq ($($(*)),)
    @echo "You must specify $(*), value was $($(*))"
    @exit 1
endif

.PHONY: say-hello
say-hello: _validate-arg-moniker  # this target requires the 'moniker' argument to be supplied
    @echo "Hello $(moniker)"
```

Calling `make say-hello moniker=John`, results in the output `You must specify moniker, value was John`.

The expected output is `Hello John`.

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible? Is there an issue when using `$(*)` or computed variables with `ifeq`?

**Update:** `ifeq` and computed variables work fine. It seems the issue is only apparent when using the wildcard value `$(*)` with `ifeq`

Comment: Note that `.PHONY: _validate-arg-%` is probably not what you think. I may be wrong but I think it only declares one target as phony: `_validate-arg-%` with a literal `%`. This is because there is no `%` character in the target part of the rule. It is thus not a pattern rule. If you want to declare all your `_validate-arg-something` as phony you will have to list them explicitly or derive them from something else (e.g., `$(addprefix _validate-arg-,$(MYLIST))`.

Comment: You are trying to use make automatic variables in conditionals. This does not work because when make analyzes the conditionals the automatic variables don't have a value yet. Try to test the make variable from inside the `_validate-arg-%` recipe with shell constructs (if [ -z "$($*)" ]; then...).

Comment: Thank you for steering me in the right direction, @RenaudPacalet. I now understand make a little more and have a working solution.